# How to split genotypes into two groups from a SNP txt file contains -1, 0 and 1 in R?

Tags: r, snp

I have a SNP file(it is 96 obs. of 1178 variables with -1, 1 and 0 and in some places NA) and I need to calculate Jaccard genetic distance from them in R. Is there any way to convert these 3 values to 0 and 1? I tried to change from -1 to 2 before for a different distance, but the Jaccard distance is binary and you cannot assign 2. Is there a way to re-code Jaccard to take into account -1 and give a good distance matrix? (Jaccard must remain binary and contain only 0 and 1). I will need it later to divide the subpopulation into 2 groups.

Here is an example input data file:

https://pbgworks.org/sites/pbgworks.org/files/snp.txt

Comment: THis should be pretty simple to achieve, but could you clarify exactly your rules - i.e. which number gets converted to which?